# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I just downloaded Tess4J from http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/ and imported it in netbeans. I am follwoing [this url](http://tphangout.com/how-to-use-the-tesseract-api-to-perform-ocr-in-your-java-code/) i followed every step properly but when i am trying to execute i am getting below error.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:75)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
    at recognizer.Recognizer.main(Recognizer.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

I searched and found that people are suggesting to  update to Visual [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40784) which i did but it turned out no help, i am still getting the same issue. I don't know what am i doing wrong below is my code.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

public class Recognizer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();//

try {

String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
System.out.println(result);

} catch (TesseractException e) {
System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: The [latest versions](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html) requires Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Packages.

Comment: @nguyenq i tried still i am getting the same error.

Comment: No solution here? :/ I am having the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it is not loading the native Dlls.

1. The Tesseract DLLs were built with VS2015 and therefore depend on the [Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587). Install it.
2. Tesseract, Ghostscript, and Leptonica Windows 32- and 64-bit DLLs are embedded in tess4j.jar and lept4j.jar, respectively. So make sure you have them on the class path.
3. Make sure you have all the dependency libraries on the class path (The Libraries can be found in Your_downloaded_Tess4J_folder\lib )
4. Make sure you have "tessdata" folder on the class path (The "tessdata" folder can be found in Your_downloaded_Tess4J_folder).

   Please read the [Tess4J Tutorial](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/) for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks i solved it before. but i found your answer helpful so i accepted it and upvoted. Please upvote my question if you find it good.